# Rails cookies with custom string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

Hello I need some help on a interesting question.

On the frontend I set a cookie with javascript called buy_456 and 456 is the id of my page.

So the cookies might be buy_345 buy_435 buy_385. On the rails views now I check if the cookie for that page is set and here is the problem. You can say `cookies[:buy]` but you can't say `cookies[:buy_@page.id]`

Is there any way to create custom strings and call them inside the cookie? Like we do with views "Some text #{@page.id}"

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it possible

```
cookie["buy_#{@page.id}".to_sym]
```